# Logrotate cronjob not running

Tags: linux, logrotate

I wish to use the following command as a cron job:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate /home/xxxx/public_html/cgi-bin/logrotate.conf -f
```

However the message is:

```
error: error creating state file /var/lib/logrotate.status: Permission
denied
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: are you executing this command as non-root user?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the output location of the status file:

```
/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /home/xxxx/logrotate/logrotate.status /home/xxxx/public_html/cgi-bin/logrotate.conf -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run the `cron` as sudoer:

`sudo /usr/sbin/logrotate /home/xxxx/public_html/cgi-bin/logrotate.conf -f`